# Change /home using Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I started using Ubuntu on windows 10 and I've noticed that the default path `/home/<user_created_during_installation>` is located in

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\<user>
```

My question is, can I change that path (and if so, how?) or do I have to work on that path while I use Ubuntu on Windows?

Thanks in advance

[image: Image on Windows]